# Calculate $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{[1,n]} ( \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!}\cdot(\frac{x}{2})^i ) \cdot(x+\sin ^{3n} (x))\cdot e^{-2x}d\lambda_1(x)$

Tags: integration

Calculate $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{[1,n]} \Big( \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!}\cdot(\frac{x}{2})^i \Big) \cdot(x+\sin ^{3n} (x))\cdot e^{-2x} d\lambda_1(x)$$

Firstly I think that I must find a function $\phi$ such that $\phi_n(x)=\Big( \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!}\cdot(\frac{x}{2})^i \Big) \cdot(x+\sin ^{3n} (x))\cdot e^{-2x} \to \phi(x)$

I know that $\phi_n(x) \to \Big( \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!}\cdot(\frac{x}{2})^i \Big) \cdot(x+0)\cdot e^{-2x}$, but I don't know what I can do with $\Big( \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!}\cdot(\frac{x}{2})^i \Big)$ to lose $n$.

Have you got some tips?

Comment: $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{k!}\cdot(\frac{x}{2})^k=e^{x/2}$